# parse huge csv file with C++

Tags: c++, stl

I order to simulate my network I am using a trace file (csv file) with a size between 5 to 30 GB. 
The csv file is a row based, where each row contains multiple fields delimited by a space and forming teh information to form a network packet:

```
3     53      4    12    1     1  2  6
```

Since the file's size could reach several GBs (millions of lines), is it better to divided it into small chunks myfile00.csv, myfile01.csv..., or I can process the entire file on the hard drive without being loaded into the memory?
I want to read the file line by line at a specific time, which is the clock cycle of the simulation, and get all information in the line to create an omnet++ message.

```
packet MyTrace::getpacket() {
int id; // first field
int cycle; // second field
int source; // third field
int destination; // fourth field
int numberofDep; // fifth field
std::list<int> listofDep; // remaining fields

if (!traceFile.is_open()) {
 // get id
 // get cycle
 // ....
}
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

EDIT:

```
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("BlackSmall.csv");
    int currentline=0 ;
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
   while (getline(myfile, line)) {  

      istringstream ss(line);
      string request;
      int id, cycle, source , dest, srcType, destType, packetSize, dependency;
      int listdep;
      std::list<int> dep; 
              ss >> id; 
              ss>> cycle; 
              ss>> source; 
              ss>> dest;
              ss>>request;
              ss>> srcType;
              ss>> destType;
              ss>> packetSize;
              ss>> dependency; 
              while (ss >> listdep) dep.push_back(listdep);
           // Create my packet

    }
    myfile.close();
    }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

With the above code, I can get all information that I need from a line.
The problem is that I need to use this code inside a class, which when I call it returns just one line's information. Is there a way how to point to a specific line when I call this class?

Comment: I don't think your question is specific to OMNeT++. If you phrase it more generally, you will likely find much better help.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, I edited the tags and the question to be more general. Hope I can get help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your application seems to require a single sequential pass through the input, so processing a file that is 1GB or 100GB is perhaps just a matter of patience and perhaps parallelism.

The approach should be to translate records line-by-line.  You should avoid strategies that attempt to read the entire file into memory.  The STL offers the easy-to-use std::ifstream class with a built-in getline method, which returns a std::string containing the line to be converted.

If you are feeling more ambitious and want to control the amount of data read or buffered more carefully then you would not be the first developer to roll-your-own code to implement a buffered reader.  This is a fairly empowering exercise and will help you think through some corner cases with reading partial lines and such.  But in the end, it probably will not give you a significant boost toward your goal.  I suspect the ifstream approach will get you up and running without the hassle and will not ultimately be the bottleneck in processing these files.

If you were really concerned about optimizing execution time then having multiple files might help you launch parallel processing tasks.

```
// define a class to hold your custom record
class Record {
};

// create a parser function to convert a line of text into the record
bool parse(std::string const &line, Record &record) {
}

// create a translator method to convert a record into the desired output
bool write(Record const &record, std::ofstream &os) {
}

// actually open input stream for the input file
std::ifstream is;
std::ofstream os;
std::string line;

while (std::getline(is,line)) {
  Record record;
  if (!parse(line,record)) break;
  if (!write(record,os)) break;
}
```

You can re-use the Record instance by moving it outside the while loop so long as you are careful to reset the variable so that information from preceding records does not taint the current record.  You can also dive head first into the C++ ecosystem by producing stream input and output operator ("<<",">>") but I personally find this approach to be more confusion than it is worth.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, you mean if I use ifstream the file will be read from the hard drive and won't be loaded into the memory? If yes, it will be my best approach since I need to read the file line by line in a sequential manner.  Can you give me more details how I can create the write function when all fields (of the same line) are separated by a space and only the last field may have multiple entries. Thanks!

Comment: Data will obviously move from disk into memory, but the `ifstream` will not attempt to move the entire file into memory at once, which is what it seems you are trying to avoid.  Instead, the code will move bits of the file into memory and give your code access to one line at a time.

Comment: Thanks, I opted for ifstream and istringstream to get what I want. Is there any way to point to a specific line?

Comment: Without other information, I do not know a way to read a specific line number.  The straightforward approach is to read through the file in a linear fashion, ignoring uninteresting lines.  Use `seekg` to position the read if you know the specific byte offset to begin the read.  Unlike the read-but-ignore approach, seeking directly to the position of interest will avoid unnecessary transfer from disk.

Comment: each line contains a packet informatio,  so under a specific condition I want to call the class to read the file and fech  a packet  ( content of a single line). The next time I call the class it needs to go to the next line. I have added a line number to each line and and counter that let me get the next line, but obviously after reading all previous ones. With a file that may contain several millions of lines, I dont think it is the best approach!

Comment: Try using`ifstream::getline`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps best approach for you would be to import your CSV file into SQLite database.

Once you import it and add some indexes, you can easily and very efficiently query necessary rows from that database. SQLite has lots of ready-to-use C/C++ client libraries available, you can start with default one at https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it will complicate my task since I am not familiar with SQL. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I'm 100% sure it will make your task a lot easier - been there, done that. The only SQL statement you need to know is `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE column = x`. Performance will be so fast, that it won't be necessary to keep data in memory.

Comment: I understand that sql will be much easier, but I need to find a library that let omnet uses databases.

Comment: Even if omnet doesn't have official database support, adding SQLite support to your project only requires to `include "sqlite3.h"`, and link `sqlite3.c` - just 2 files.

Comment: thanks! can you give an example how the code will look like?

Comment: This is very good tutorial how to use SQLite c library: http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitec.